# Unable to go to next page after successfully added data to database

Tags: php

Currently, I do the room booking. My scenario is after I added data and click the add button, it cannot redirect to the next page it stick with the same page. My current page is add_factory.php

Same goes happen when the data insert is duplicated, the alert message doesn't appear although I create the alert js.

Below is my current PHP code.

```
    <?php

    require_once "../../config/configPDO.php";
    require_once "../../config/check.php";

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
      //Getting Post Values
      $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];
      // Query for validation of username and email-id
      $ret="SELECT * FROM factory where (Fac_ID=:Fac_ID)";
      $queryt = $conn -> prepare($ret);
      $queryt->bindParam(':Fac_ID',$Fac_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $queryt -> execute();
      $results = $queryt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
          if($queryt -> rowCount() == 0)
          {
          // Query for Insertion
          $sql="INSERT INTO factory(Fac_Name, Fac_ID) VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_ID)";
          $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
          // Binding Post Values
          $query->bindparam(':Fac_Name', $Fac_ID);
          $query->bindparam(':Fac_ID', $Fac_ID);
          $query->execute();
          $lastInsertId = $conn->lastInsertId();

              if($lastInsertId){

                header("Location:factory.php");

              }else{

                echo "
                <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
                <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
                ";

              }
            }
    else{

      echo "
      <script>alert('The factory you add is already exist')</script>
      <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
      ";

        }
    }

    ?>
```

this is my form

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <table width="90%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"><b>Factory Name</b></td>
            <td width="50%"><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" class="form-control" name="Fac_ID" required></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to add this factory?');">
    </form>
```

Can anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Can you also post your form html in your question? Make sure your form use `POST` method and your submit button has `name='Submit'` attribute

Comment: When you submit the form, Is the new data inserted into the database?

Comment: @catcon already edited

Comment: More than likely there's an error so it never gets to the redirect. Add this to the top of the page `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` It looks to me like the problem is here `$queryt->bindParam(':Fac_ID',$Fac_ID,PDO::PARAM_STR);`, is `:Fac_ID` an integer? Also, for your insert you don't specify the data type when you bind the params. You should really use `bindValue()` unless you need to bind by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

> it cannot redirect to the next page it stick with the same page

it's because of this, it will load in the same page:

```
header("Location:factory.php");
```

and this:

```
window.location = 'factory.php'
```

Second,the duplicate alert won't appear because the page itself is already loading in `factory.php`
So change your code from:

```
  echo "
  <script>alert('The factory you add is already exist')</script>
  <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
  ";
```

to:

```
  echo "
  <script>alert('The factory you add is already exist');
  window.open("factory.php", "_blank");</script>
  ";
```

The `window.open("factory.php", "_blank");` means it will redirect to other page, not on the same page.

Lastly, don't forget to add `;` to every statement